# Prove that bias of MLE for Weibull process

Tags: estimators, weibull-distribution

In the case of fixed observation interval $[0,T]$ of a Weibull process, I learned that the MLE of the shape parameter $\beta$ and MLE of the scale parameter $\alpha$ are as follow:

$$\frac{1}{\hat{\beta}_T}=\ln T -\frac{1}{N_T}\sum_{i=1}^{N_T}\ln T_i\\
\ln\hat{\alpha}_T=\ln T -\frac{1}{\hat{\beta}}\ln N_T$$

I would like to study the bias of these estimators. From Internet I find that these two estimators are biased but I do not know how to prove them. We have that $N_T \sim \mathcal{P}(\int_0^T \lambda(u)du)$, but I don't know the distribution of $T_i$. So how can I compute the bias in this case?

Comment: As a starting point for others, can you give links to where you found information about bias on the Internet?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwib1quOua_hAhVtx1kKHVCHB5QQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2297-8747%2F22%2F1%2F19%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw1UyQFUUeWK0E41D7fNH3Pt

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, here it is http://web5.uottawa.ca/www5/dcousineau/home/Others/DistriFitting/Docs/35-Jacquelin.pdf